# Java file construction - why am I getting different results?

Tags: java, file

I've just stumbled on a weird scenario and am wondering if anyone can explain this behaviour.

Case 1:

```
File base = new File("");
System.out.println(base.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(base.isDirectory());
System.out.println(base.canRead());
```

Result:

```
C:\workspace-sss\Commons
false
false
```

Case 2:

```
File base = new File("C:/workspace-sss/Commons");
System.out.println(base.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(base.isDirectory());
System.out.println(base.canRead());
```

Result:

```
C:\workspace-sss\Commons
true
true
```

If the absolute path of the two File objects are equal, why are they treated differently?

Comment: FYI constructing the file as follows: new File("").getAbsoluteFile(); has the desired effect.

Comment: File.separatorChar. http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar

Comment: separator has no effect in this case. generally speaking, "/" works whereas "\" will only work on windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you used `new File(".")`, you should get the correct results for the current directory.

Comment: but why ... i'm not asking how to get the desired result, but whether there's logic to the behavior.

Comment: Well, because "" is not a valid file name, whereas "." is (and refers to the current directory). So, the fact that "" even partially works is, in my view, purely accidental.

Comment: fair enough! i'd expect an exception rather than a broken object though.